# Как удалить строку в двумерном массиве?

Tags: c, указатели, память, динамические-массивы

Допустим, у меня есть двумерный массив состоящий из 3 строк. Мне нужно удалить 2 строку к примеру. Как это сделать?

```
char* GetLine(){
  char* text = NULL;
  char ch;
  int counter;
  for(counter = 1 ;; counter++){
    ch = getchar();
    text = (char*)realloc(text,counter*sizeof(char));
    if(ch != '\n'){
      *(text+counter-1) = ch;
    }
    else{
      *(text+counter-1) = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
  return text;
}

int main(void) {
    // Disable stdout buffering
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    char **lines = NULL;
    int i;
    lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);
    for(i = 0; i < 3;i++){
     *(lines+i) = GetLine();
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      puts(*(lines+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как в любом массиве любых элементов

Пусть имеем `T array[N]`, и надо удалить элемент номер `M`:

```
memmove(array+M,            // адрес M-го элемента
        array+M+1,          // адрес M+1-го элемента
        sizeof(T)*(N-M-1)); // количество байт
```

*Перед* этим вы должны выполнить все необходимые действия по очистке `M`-го элемента - например, если это указатель на динамически выполненную память - освободить ее.
*После* этого вы должны помнить, что в массиве - `N-1` элемент и работать соответственно. Если очень хочется - можно вызвать `realloc`.

Ваш двумерный массив по сути - одномерный массив указателей на динамически выделенную память.

И, кстати, за вот такое

```
for(counter = 1 ;; counter++){
    ch = getchar();
    text = (char*)realloc(text,counter*sizeof(char));
```

я бы снижал оценку. Не дело для каждого символа вызывать `realloc` - это не экономия, а расточительство...

Comment: Спасибо, насчет последнего, Вы я так понимаю советуете заранее выделять n-ое кол-во памяти, а затем корректировать в случае нехватки/избытка памяти?

Comment: Да, в зависимости от задачи. Если это ввод человеком - то для начала 100 символов должно хватить :) А далее - увеличивать в некоторое количество раз. А уже потом, когда введено - и если превышение выделенной памяти над реально необходимой критично для программы и системы - то тогда уже применять `realloc`.

Comment: @harry, это не только тормоза, но и откровенный баг в коде

Comment: @0andriy Какой именно? Навскидку вижу только, что `ch` должен быть `int`'ом, и что нет проверки `text` после `realloc`..

Answer (score 0):

Один из возможных вариантов работы с массивом указателей.

```
typedef struct s_line_ s_line 
struct s_line_
{
  char ** str;
  int number;
  int amount;
};
#define AMOUNT_LINE   10
int alloc_line(s_line *line)
{
 int t;
 char ** str;
 if(line->amount == 0){
  t = AMOUNT_LINE;
 }
 else{
  t = (line->amount << 1);
 }
 str = (char **)malloc((sizeof(char*)*t));
 memset(str,0,t);
 if(line->str != NULL){
   memmove(str,line->str,line->amount);
   free(line->str);
 }
 line-str = str;
 return 0;
}
int add_str(s_line * line,char * str)
{ 
  if(line->amount == line->number){
   alloc_line(line);
  }
  line->str[line->number] = str;
  line->number ++; 
  return 0;
} 
int remove_str(s_line * line,int number)
{ 
  char * str;
  char ** dest,src; 
  if(number >= line->number){
    return -1;
  }
  str = line->str[number];
  free(str);
  dest = line->str;
  src = line->str;
  dest += number;
  src += (number+1);
  memmove(dest,src,((line->number - 1) - number));
  line->number--;
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
 s_line line = {0};
 char * str;

 for(i = 0; i < 5;i++){
  str = GetLine();
  add_line(&line,str); 
 }

 for(i = 0; i < line.number; i++){
  puts(lines.str[i]);
 }      

  remove_str(&line,2);
  return 0;
}
```